# Android locale mess?

Tags: java, android, locale

For the function in Android `Locale.getISOLanguages()` there is the following documentation comment:

```
/**
 * Returns an array of strings containing all the two-letter ISO 639-1 language codes that can be
 * used as the language code when constructing a {@code Locale}.
 */
public static String[] getISOLanguages() {
    return ICU.getISOLanguages();
}
```

But when I log the array I get all kinds of codes:

`[aa, ab, ace, ach, ada, ady, ae, af, afa, afh, agq, ain, ak, akk, ale, alg, alt, am, an, ang, anp, apa, ar, arc, arn, arp, art, arw, as, asa, ast, ath, aus, av, awa, ay, az, ba, bad, bai, bal, ban, bas, bat, bax, bbj, be, bej, bem, ber, bez, bfd, bg, bh, bho, bi, bik, bin, bkm, bla, bm, bn, bnt, bo, br, bra, brx, bs, bss, btk, bua, bug, bum, byn, byv, ca, cad, cai, car, cau, cay, cch, ce, ceb, cel, cgg, ch, chb, chg, chk, chm, chn, cho, chp, chr, chy, ckb, cmc, co, cop, cpe, cpf, cpp, cr, crh, crp, cs, csb, cu, cus, cv, cy, da, dak, dar, dav, day, de, del, den, dgr, din, dje, doi, dra, dsb, dua, dum, dv, dyo, dyu, dz, dzg, ebu, ee, efi, egy, eka, el, elx, en, enm, eo, es, et, eu, ewo, fa, fan, fat, ff, fi, fil, fiu, fj, fo, fon, fr, frm, fro, frr, frs, fur, fy, ga, gaa, gay, gba, gd, gem, gez, gil, gl, gmh, gn, goh, gon, gor, got, grb, grc, gsw, gu, guz, gv, gwi, ha, hai, haw, he, hi, hil, him, hit, hmn, ho, hr, hsb, ht, hu, hup, hy, hz, ia, iba, ibb, id, ie, ig, ii, ijo, ik, ilo, inc, ine, inh, io, ira, iro, is, it, iu, ja, jbo, jgo, jmc, jpr, jrb, jv, ka, kaa, kab, kac, kaj, kam, kar, kaw, kbd, kbl, kcg, kde, kea, kfo, kg, kha, khi, kho, khq, ki, kj, kk, kkj, kl, kln, km, kmb, kn, ko, kok, kos, kpe, kr, krc, krl, kro, kru, ks, ksb, ksf, ksh, ku, kum, kut, kv, kw, ky, la, lad, lag, lah, lam, lb, lez, lg, li, lkt, ln, lo, lol, loz, lt, lu, lua, lui, lun, luo, lus, luy, lv, mad, maf, mag, mai, mak, man, map, mas, mde, mdf, mdr, men, mer, mfe, mg, mga, mgh, mgo, mh, mi, mic, min, mis, mk, mkh, ml, mn, mnc, mni, mno, mo, moh, mos, mr, ms, mt, mua, mul, mun, mus, mwl, mwr, my, mye, myn, myv, na, nah, nai, nap, naq, nb, nd, nds, ne, new, ng, nia, nic, niu, nl, nmg, nn, nnh, no, nog, non, nqo, nr, nso, nub, nus, nv, nwc, ny, nym, nyn, nyo, nzi, oc, oj, om, or, os, osa, ota, oto, pa, paa, pag, pal, pam, pap, pau, peo, phi, phn, pi, pl, pon, pra, pro, ps, pt, qu, raj, rap, rar, rm, rn, ro, roa, rof, rom, ru, rup, rw, rwk, sa, sad, sah, sai, sal, sam, saq, sas, sat, sba, sbp, sc, scn, sco, sd, se, see, seh, sel, sem, ses, sg, sga, sgn, shi, shn, shu, si, sid, sio, sit, sk, sl, sla, sm, sma, smi, smj, smn, sms, sn, snk, so, sog, son, sq, sr, srn, srr, ss, ssa, ssy, st, su, suk, sus, sux, sv, sw, swb, swc, syc, syr, ta, tai, te, tem, teo, ter, tet, tg, th, ti, tig, tiv, tk, tkl, tl, tlh, tli, tmh, tn, to, tog, tpi, tr, trv, ts, tsi, tt, tum, tup, tut, tvl, tw, twq, ty, tyv, tzm, udm, ug, uga, uk, umb, und, ur, uz, vai, ve, vi, vo, vot, vun, wa, wae, wak, wal, war, was, wen, wo, xal, xh, xog, yao, yap, yav, ybb, yi, yo, ypk, yue, za, zap, zbl, zen, zgh, zh, znd, zu, zun, zxx, zza]`

And then also `Locale.getDefault().getLanguage()` returns `ar-eg` for Arabic-English when it clearly says that languages codes are two letter ISO-639-1 at the top of the file..

What's up with this?

Any other way to get ISO-639-1 compliant code?

Answer (score 1):

You could try getISO3Language(), a method of the Locale class.

The whole Locale thing is a mess starting with the various competing international bodies that don't understand how to represent i18n or i10n stuff in a sensible way.
That is followed up by a rather messy effort to implement their meanderings in the java.util.Locale class (Take a look at the ResourceBundle usage if you need an example).
It really has nothing to do with Android.
Best of luck.